# How do I write a database driven dropdown selection to a label?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Another ASP.NET C# noobie question...

The following codebehind populates a dropdown list from a database. There are three columns in the table (ID, ItemType & BinType). I need to be able to return the correct BinType for the row selected by the user:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

using System.Data.OleDb;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

  // Global variable for SqlConnection
  OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {

      // specifying sqlconnection string
      con.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString_GRPAS_dev"].ConnectionString;
      {
        // Select rows from database where the ItemType field isn't empty. Sort them alphabetically by ItemType
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM NF_WhatWasteWhere WHERE ItemType <>'' Order By ItemType"))
        {
          //Open the connection and populate the dropdown list with ID and Itemtype
          cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

          cmd.Connection = con;

          con.Open();

          ItemType1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();

          ItemType1.DataTextField = "ItemType";

          ItemType1.DataValueField = "ID";

          ItemType1.DataBind();

          con.Close();

        }

      }
      // Add a non selectable "Select Item" row at the top of the dropdown list
      ItemType1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Item--", "0"));


    }

  }
    protected void ItemType1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      //
      // *** Stuff needs to go here in order to continue with the following conditional statement ***
      //

        if (ItemType1.SelectedValue == "Green")
        {
          BinResultTest.Text = "<div class='greenBin results'><div class='arrow'></div><p>" + ItemType1.SelectedItem + " should be disposed of in a <strong>green bin</strong>.</p></div>";
        }
        else if (ItemType1.SelectedValue == "Black")
        {
          BinResultTest.Text = "<div class='blackBin results'><div class='arrow'></div><p>" + ItemType1.SelectedItem + " should be disposed of in a <strong>black bin</strong>.</p></div>";
        }
        else
        {
          BinResultTest.Text = "<div class='noBin results'><div class='arrow'></div><p>" + ItemType1.SelectedItem + " should <strong>NOT</strong> be disposed of in a green or black bin.</p></div>";
        }

    }
}
```

What do I need to do to get the conditional statement to work? I presume I need to run another database query - something like the following:

```
SELECT BinType FROM NF_WhatWasteWhere WHERE ID=" + ItemType1.DataValueField
```

However, I'm not sure how to code this to establish the connection and return the result.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by Conditional Statement.  I think I can help with this issue, but I'm not exactly sure what you are asking.

Comment: I mean the If / Else stuff at the bottom of the code - it's meant to check what the value of the returned rows' BinType is and then write the corresponding HTML to the label.

Answer (score 0):

Edit***
Okay then in `protected void ItemType1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)`

You can do something similar to what you did with your first query but use an `OdbcDataReader`

```
    string binValue;
    int idHolder = ItemType1.SelectedValue;
        con.ConnectionString =System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString_GRPAS_dev"].ConnectionString;
              {
               using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT BinType FROM NF_WhatWasteWhere WHERE ID = @Id;"))
                {
                  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id",idHolder);
                  cmd.Connection = con;

                  con.Open();
        OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if(reader.Read())
        {
          if(!DBNull.Value.Equals(reader["BinType"]))
            {
             binValue = Convert.ToString(reader["BinType"]);
             }
       }
     con.Close();

//Then all your conditionals based off of binValue....
```

Something like this but maybe a bit more well writen.

Comment: I've tried that but the results in my label default to the first item in the table that has that particular BinField instead of the actual selected item.

Comment: Thanks, but I get an error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader' to 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader'

Comment: It's the line "OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();" which causes the error.

Comment: oops my fault  try OleDbDataReader instead of OdbcDataReader.  I was trying to type fast and put the wrong reader in.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I already spotted that and replaced it. Unfortunately it then gives me a new error: Must declare the scalar variable "@Id".

Comment: I adjusted my example from earlier by adding an int variable could you run debug and see if `idHolder` is coming in blank if so that would cause the scalar error as their would be nothing in `@Id`.